# some words be bold in citiation

Tags: bold, bibliographystyle

I am writing my proposal and there are some words be bold such as and, pages and volume. I want all be in normal style.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul} % hightlight package
\usepackage{multirow, multicol, tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\usepackage[backend=BibLaTeX,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage[caption=true]{subfigure}
```

and in the References.bib:

```
@inproceedings{akindoyin2015modelling,
  title={Modelling and estimation of carrier frequency and phase uncertainties in large aperture arrays},
  author={Akindoyin, Akinbiyi},
  booktitle={2015 IEEE International Conference on Communications (ICC)},
  pages={4715--4720},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}

%4
@phdthesis{willerton2013array,
  title={Array auto-calibration},
  author={Willerton, Marc},
  year={2013},
  school={Citeseer}
}

%5
@article{he2010wideband,
  title={Wideband MIMO systems: Signal design for transmit beampattern     synthesis},
  author={He, Hao and Stoica, Petre and Li, Jian},
  journal={IEEE transactions on Signal Processing},
  volume={59},
  number={2},
  pages={618--628},
  year={2010},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

%6
@inproceedings{patton2008modulus,
  title={Modulus constraints in adaptive radar waveform design},
  author={Patton, Lee K and Rigling, Brian D},
  booktitle={2008 IEEE Radar Conference},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2008},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

I use bibtex

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of incompatible packages in your code:

- `cite`/`natbib` vs. `biblatex`: you have to choose between a classical bibtex bibliography, in which case you can use the first two packages and a more modern and flexible biblatex bases bibliography. Pick one, but don't combine both
- `backend=BibLaTeX` does  not exist. It has to be either `biber` or `bibtex` (I suggest biber, that gives you more power)
- the combination of all these algorithm packages will throw an error. Choose the ones you need and don't load all of them
- `subcaption` vs. `subfigure` are incompatible. Pick one and only one.
- the `appendix` package will also lead to an error about `\appendix` already defined. Don't ignore error messages

---

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul} % hightlight package
\usepackage{multirow, multicol, tabularx}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
%\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
%\usepackage[caption=true]{subfigure}



\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]